# SQL After insert trigger insert multiple rows into another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

So i have the following table:

```
Table: competence
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
name    varchar(400)
organization_id int(11)
competence_type_id  int(11)
competence_category_id  int(11)
```

And the following user table:

```
    Table: user
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
username    varchar(100)
password    varchar(100)
is_active   int(11)
user_type_id    int(11)
token   varchar(445)
organization_id int(11)
title_id    int(11)
image_path  varchar(100)
division_id int(11)
```

And the following connection between these two tables:

```
Table: user_has_competence
Columns:
user_id int(11) PK
competence_id   int(11) PK
competence_level_id int(11)
progression varchar(45)
id  int(11) AI PK
```

Now im trying to create a trigger on the `competence` table that does the following:

After a row has been inserted into the competence table find all users with the same organization_id and then for each of these users insert into user_has_competence with the user_id and competence_id.

However i havnt worked with triggers that much and was hoping one of you guys could push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In mysql it could be done as

```
delimiter //
create trigger competence_ins after insert on competence
for each row 
begin
 insert into user_has_competence (user_id,competence_id)
 select u.id,c.id from competence c
 join user u on u.organization_id = c.organization_id and c.organization_id = new.organization_id;
end;//

delimiter;
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate! :D +1  do you know how i would do whenever i create a user it should add all competences from the competence table where the organization_id is the same?

Comment: Yes it would be pretty much same. if you provide an example I can write a query for that.

Comment: Actually when you add an user you also add organization_id and in competence table you have organization_id. So if you insert into `user_has_competence` it may happen that for same organization id there multiple data so do you want each of them and newly added user_id into the `user_has_competence` ?

Comment: what i need is basicly: When a new user is added to the database it automaticly adds all competences to competence_has_user and when a new competence has been added then all users in the organization has to get the competence

Comment: Well that perhaps going to have some logical issue, since when you add any user you do not know anything about `competence`, all you can get those data from competence having same organization id into the `user_has_competence` now say you add a new `competence` and using same trigger you may have duplicate entry. So I would suggest to make it one way. I would suggest to create a new question.